# JIRA GreenHopper Release Status

Tags: jira, release-management, greenhopper

We have a JIRA installation in our company with GreenHopper and we are currently dabbling with it. Typically (in VersionOne), we create releases, add items to it which becomes the release backlog. From this release backlog, we pick up items for each sprint.

At any point of time, I can track the running sprint's status and also the release status. With JIRA, I seem to be missing this release status tracking. Am I looking at the wrong place or is it just not there.

Whenever I search for releases, I end up with when a sprint is released and thats not what I am looking for.

More Info: Based on further investigation, there is something called as 'Classic Boards'. Those have releases and sprints underneath them. That lets me track both the release and sprint but setting up parent child relationship between them. This classic board is no longer supported. If so, how do I do the same in new boards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic boards are definitely still supported, you can feel free to continue using them. We hope to implement some additional release planning functionality in the new boards in the near future.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Thanks Shaun. We will switch to Classic boards until release planning support is added to the new boards. Its a bummer, as we liked the swimlanes in the new boards, especially the ability to categorize based on assignee.